# HTTP persistent connection vs TCP socket connection

Tags: http, tcp, persistent

From [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) article on Wikipedia:

> Keepalive messages were not officially
>   supported in HTTP 1.0. In HTTP 1.1 all
>   connections are considered persistent,
>   unless declared otherwise.

- Does this mean that using this
  mechanism I can actually simulate a
  TCP socket connection?
- Using this    can I make a Server
  "push" data to a    client?
- Are all HTTP connections, even the
  one I am using to connect to Stack
  Overflow "HTTP persistent"?
- Does the [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technology of
  server push use this mechanism of
  HTTP persistent connection to push
  data to clients?

Comment: HTTP persistent connections are just an optimization. There is no behavior difference. If you want to stream data to the client, you can use the chunked encoding, I believe.

Comment: @derobert: what is chunked encoding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> - Does this mean that using this mechanism I can actually simulate a
>     TCP socket connection?

Not really, sockets have **MANY** more features and flexibility.

> - Using this can I make a Server "push" data to a client?

Not directly, it's *still* a request/response protocol; the persistent connection just means the client can use the same underlying socket to send multiple requests and receive the respective responses.

> - Are all HTTP connections, even the one I am using to connect to Stack
>     Overflow "HTTP persistent"?

Unless your browser (or a peculiar server) says otherwise, yes.

> - Does the COMET technology of server push use this mechanism of HTTP
>     persistent connection to push data to
>     clients?

Kinda (for streaming, at least), but with a lot of whipped cream on top. There are other Comet implementation approaches, such as hidden iframes and AJAX long polling, that may not require persistent connections (which give *some* firewalls &c the fits anyway;-).

Comment: You say "sockets have MANY more features and flexibility". What are these features vis a vis  HTTP persistent connection and what flexibility do they provide?

Comment: TCP sockets impose no restrictions on who speaks when or how -- either party can send bytes any time without waiting for the other ("full duplex"), the stream is not intrinsically chunked up into messages of defined length, &c. You need a higher-layer protocol on top to give up some of the flexibility and turn chaos to order: HTTP is just one such protocol, an asymmetrical half-duplex request/response protocol with messages of well-defined length (content-length headers or chunking). Client may enqueue requests one after the other, server must respond to each request.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the HTTP server can "push" data to a connected http client without the client requesting it. See "HTTP server push" at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology. However it does seem to be commonly implemented.